# How to insert JSONB data from dependent table

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to insert data into a JSONB field based on a dependent table.

Essentially I want to do this (ignore why this is just an example query):

```
insert into myschema.teams (team_name, params)
select users.team_name, '{"team_name": teams.team_id, "user_name": users.username }'
from myschema.users
where users.team_name is not null;
```

As written I'm getting these errors:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 2: ... '{"team_name...
            ^                                                 
DETAIL:  Token "teams" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"team_name": teams...
```

Comment: Where does `teams.team_name` come from? Did you do a join in the query?

Comment: Bad example. I wanted the id that was generated during the inserting of a record to teams. I edited that to be `team_id`

Comment: Well for the team name you could just refer to the `users.team_name` again. For the default-generated `team_id`, no I don't think you can reference that from an `insert` statement. But you really shouldn't need to put that in the JSON data, so that the row contains the id twice?

Comment: You're write. In converting to this example I realized I put the wrong field. I don't actually need it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a string literal that doesn't contain valid JSON. There is no interpolation going on - you need use the [`jsonb_build_object` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) to create the JSONB value from dynamic values. (You could also do string concatenation and the cast from text to json, but please don't).

```
insert into myschema.teams (team_name, params)
select users.team_name, jsonb_build_object('team_name', teams.team_name, 'user_name', users.username)
from myschema.users
where users.team_name is not null;
```